# How to mount /proc in Docker Container

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile, docker-build, procfs

Why can't I mount the `/proc` device from the container during the build process?

If I run `docker build -t test .` with this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM debian:stable-slim
RUN bash -c 'ls {/proc,/dev,/sys}'
```

I can see that all special devices are populated. But if I try this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM debian:stable-slim
RUN bash -c 'ls {/proc,/dev,/sys}'
RUN mount --bind /proc /mnt
```

I get the following error:

```
mount: /mnt: permission denied.
The command '/bin/sh -c mount --bind /proc /mnt' returned a non-zero code: 32
```

I know it's possible to use `--privileged` mode in `docker run`, but my goal is not to access the host's `/proc` but to just mount the `/proc` device from container in a file system that I'm generating inside the container with `debootstrap`. So that I can install some packages, specifically [default-jre](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/default-jre).

My Docker Version: `20.10.8`

**EDIT**

My goal is to create a custom live-cd like [here](https://willhaley.com/blog/custom-debian-live-environment/), so I can't use the container's base OS.

Comment: Docker mounts /proc before it starts the container process, and at that point, nothing else is permitted.

Comment: I need to debootstrap a system inside container and install some packages. There is any workaround?

Comment: If you're starting `FROM debian`, you already have the base OS available; you don't need to run low-level first-time installation tools like `debootstrap`.

Comment: My goal is to create a custom live-cd like [here](https://willhaley.com/blog/custom-debian-live-environment/), so I can't use the base OS.

Comment: Did you ever find a workaround to this?

Comment: @rgov unfortunately not.